# What does it mean for $2\pi = 1$ in a "private system of units"?

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, units, absolute-units

I saw the following image of an excerpt from Robert Mill's Tutorial on Infinities in QED, floating about the internet:

[image: Tutorial on Infinities in QED]

The book is available [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2720-5_3), however I don't think I have access to it, unless perhaps my university grants me access on some other platform. Hence, I'm unsure of the credibility of the image.

Assuming it's there's no typo and/or the image isn't doctored, although I understand it's quite common to normalize $\hbar$ and $c$ among other constants to $1$, what does it mean to have $2\pi=i=1$?

**EDIT:** I found a preview of the book available [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ckXtBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22i+am+using+a+private+system+of+units+in+which%22&source=bl&ots=tb6Ezq-Jif&sig=ACfU3U3wXR_GL4-gDMitHDwf0WkWWsTJ7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmhfCn6prwAhWGIjQIHcn0C2oQ6AEwAHoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=%22i%20am%20using%20a%20private%20system%20of%20units%20in%20which%22&f=false) which does indeed include all the same text shown in the image.

Comment: You can't actually set $2 \pi = i = 1$. He means that he's being sloppy because he doesn't want to keep track of the details.

Comment: I suspect the author is being somewhat tongue in cheek and means he is not bothering to write factors of $2\pi$ or $i$ which may appear in the equations. The final results may thus need to be scaled by a small  finite factor, which won't affect the gist of the argument.

Comment: He probably knows a number of heuristics built up from experience for where to insert the factors of $2\pi$ and $i$ correctly at the end and so doesn't keep track of them during the calculation.